# Mejor manera de agregar datos a una lista en firebase database

Tags: java, android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase

Estoy usando Firebase realtime db y estaba intentando almacenar para un usuario una lista de "Animales".

Estructura de la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero lograr es que por ejemplo: para el usuario con "Uuid" 11111 le aparezcan una lista con los animales que va publicando. Es decir:

```
Fireabase-root
    |
    --- 11111
          |
          --- animal1 
                |
                --- descripcion: "algo"
                |
                --- edad: "algo"
                |
                --- nombre: "algo"
                |
                --- raza: "algo"

           --- animal2
               ...
           --- animal3
               ...
```

Queria saber cual es la mejor forma de poder realizar esto. Pensaba en que el child "animal1" sea una key y para cada animal que se vaya generando se agregue una key distinta, pero no se si es la mejor manera de resolverlo.
Intente probar con el metodo push que vi que te genera una key, pero no se bien como usarlo. Dejo lo que fui probando.

```
DatabaseReference nombre = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Animales").child(userId).push().child("nombre");
nombre.setValue("Leon");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estás pensando esta en lo correcto

```
DatabaseReference nombre = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Animales").child(userId).push().child("nombre");
nombre.setValue("Leon");
```

Lo que estás haciendo es que bajo tu usuario unico cuyo id es userId estas creando un nuevo animal con un valor alfanumerico random con `.push()` lo cual te da la posibilidad de poder crear N animales bajo ese usuario y que su identificador unico no se repita, puedes crear 5 leones con distintas caracteristicas ya que cada uno tiene su propia referencia bajo Animales

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por responder!